# To migrate from AWS EC2 to Google Compute Engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to launch a Compute Engine instance from a EC2 snapshot of Amazon, I want the exact same image of my existing EC2 disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import a Linux Amazon Machine Image (AMI) to Compute Engine and use the image to create a new VM instance. The steps to do so are documented here - [Importing an Amazon Machine Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image#import_an_ami_image).

Comment: Oh I didn't see that, thanks though! That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is with 3rd party software that copies the machine at the block level into Compute Engine.  While image conversion, to Faizan's point, is technically possible, it's generally not the simplest route to go.  Furthermore it cannot be used when certain premium operating systems are involved, notably Windows.
The recommended approach would be to use a tool like CloudEndure http://info.cloudendure.com/Google-Cloud-Platform-Free-Migration.html.

Comment: I did checked it with RHEL 6, which else premium operating systems are you referreing to?

Comment: Windows is the most common one that can't be imported this way

Comment: @BrianStark, in your personal experience, what is the best way to migrate from one GCloud Compute Engine instance to another?  GCloud is giving me the options "CloudEndure," Velostrata," and "Turbonomic" link recommending Turbonomic [here](https://www.itcentralstation.com/products/comparisons/cloudendure-live-migration_vs_velostrata).  I wasn't sure which method to use, and didn't find any objective data comparing the methods (ie. a simple Amazon rating system)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to update this thread to reflect that Google now offers a VM Import service, which can be accessed via the Cloud Console (Import VM button).  This service is free to use, although you will be billed normally for running VMs in GCE